# Read .csv function only reading first line

Tags: c++, readfile, getline

This following code is only reading the first value of the .csv file (3.9)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

void read_train() {
    std::ifstream read("test.csv");
    std::vector<double> store;
    std::string line;
    while (getline(read, line)) {
        double x;
        x = std::stod(line.c_str());
        store.push_back(x);
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
    read.close();
}

int main() {
    read_train();
}
```

Below is the .csv file:

```
3.9
37.3
0
14.1
8
16.3
29.1
16.1
18.3
0
```

Thank you very much for assisting!

Comment: `csv` usually means values delimited by commas. You might consider replacing the contents of the loop with just `std::cout << line << "\n";` to see what you're actually reading. This works reading the input you've shown from stdin. https://ideone.com/Llu4fK Reading from a file with the same contents should be no different. A debugger is a useful tool for figuring out what is going on when behavior is unexpected.

Comment: I made that edit and now my code reads 08.3.

Comment: Did you debug your code? Did you you see that getline reads all numbers at one time, but not only the first one? Your situation can be reproduced if an end of line in csv file is \r. In this case you should call getline(read, line, '\r'). Or you can change end of line in the file to \r\n and your code will work.

Comment: You read 08.03 because you actually read "3.9\r37.3\r0\r14.1\r8\r16.3\r29.1\r16.1\r18.3\r0". Char \r is carriage return, not new line. So in console output all numbers are printed in one line, where next number overwrite previous number from the beginning of the line.

Comment: If you really don't have any delimiters in the file, just numbers, then something like this is much simpler. `double temp; while (read >> temp) { store.push_back(temp); }`